# Why does IFRAME in a TD cause excess spacing on the bottom?

Tags: html, iframe, html-table, doctype

When I put an `IFRAME` in a `TD`, I get excess spacing at the bottom of the `TD`. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.contentOnly {
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  Top
  <table class="contentOnly" style="background-color: black; width: 200; height: 200">
    <tr class="contentOnly">
      <td class="contentOnly">
        <iframe class="contentOnly" src="" frameborder="0" width="200" height="200" style="background-color: red">
        </iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Bottom
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I see:

[image: Example of spacing below IFRAME]

I am testing with Chrome. The `TD` is 204 in height. Even if I explicitly set 200 `height` and `max-height` on the `TD`, it is rendered with 204 height. The `IFRAME` is correctly 200 height.

Another interesting fact is if I omit `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` then the spacing below the `IFRAME` is not added (exactly what I want).

What is the appropriate way to add an `IFRAME` to a `TD` without having excess spacing?

Comment: Have you tried setting CSS `display: block` to the iFrame?

Comment: Yes! That did work, but why? If you put it as an answer I will mark it as answer, thanks!